# Attaching 4x6 rafter to ledger

Tags: porch

I am building a porch... and I want to use 4x6 32 OC rather than 2x6 16 OC (with 2x6 T&G roofing which will be exposed underneath.)

I am struggling with how to connect the 4x6 to the 2x8 ledger.  I cant find a hanger from Simpson, and there must be a way to do this.  Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: 3-1/2" by 5-1/2" actual?

Comment: Are you opposed to notching the ends of the rafters to 3"?